# realloc() : Invalid pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc, double-pointer

Net is a structure which contain

```
typedef struct net{
    int numele;
    struct net **e;
} net;
```

The following code raises the error:

> realloc(): invalid pointer

The realloc is causing problems whenever it is accessed and gives the above error. I don't understand why. If you think there is no problem in this part of the code, let me know because the whole code is 800 line long so i don't think I can post it here.

```
void add(net *n, net *ne) {
    if(n->numele==0) {
        n->e = (net **)malloc(sizeof(net *));
        n->e[0] = ne;
        n->numele = 1;
    } else {
        n->e = (net **)realloc(n->e, (1 + n->numele)*sizeof(net *));
        n->e[n->numele] = ne;
        n->numele = n->numele + 1;
    }
}
```

The nets `n` and `ne` are already initialized somewhere else in the code, so  you can assume that they will not be null.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - I learned a neat feature of comments the other day, if you enter the markup `[mcve]` is expands to [mcve].

Comment: @StoryTeller Right, that's the way it is, also helps while suggesting [edit].

Comment: Posted code seems OK if rather inefficient (except return value of malloc/realloc is not checked). The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that `numele` is zero in the first run?

Comment: You'll need to provide a simple `main()` so that we can see how `n` and `ne` are initialized.  Simply asserting that "somewhere else in the code" is all correct isn't very convincing.  Please [edit] your question so that it has a [mcve] that anyone can reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Code for `realloc()` seems to be OK. But if `net *n` is not initialized properly in  first call of `add()`, ie `numele != 0 && e != NULL`.  In such cases `e` might have some junk values and `realloc()` tries with invalid address. So that error can happen.